# latex error : file geometry.sty not found

Tags: installing

Ii download MiKTeX in my windows in order to be able use latex in RMarkdown and I got this error

latex error : file geometry.sty not found

could you please help me ?

Comment: Well, open MiKTeX Package Manager and install the geometry package.

Comment: thanks, please tell me what do you mean by open the miktex Package Manager ?

Comment: You have a MiKTeX console, which has tabs for installing packages, updating, managing the fonts database, &c. You'll find it in the Start Menu.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the MikTeX Console. This is an app independent from TeXwork, so you have to open it from windows. You can find it in the start menu or by typing the name in the search bar. Then click on the Packages Tab, right click on the package you want to install, then install.